# Wrapping MongoDB calls within a Promise

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, promise, node-fibers

I'm using Meteor (1.0.3) in general, but for one particular case I'm using a raw server side route to render a file -- so I'm outside a Meteor method.

I'm using node fs.writeFile/fs.readFile and exec commands to call out to Linux command-line utilities too.

My only point in brining this up is that the node calls are async of course.  And so I'm opted to use the node Q library in order to manage async callbacks.

This all worked until I added a line to call out to the MongoDB database.

A call like so:

```
var record_name = Mongo_Collection_Name.findOne({_personId: userId}, {fields: {'_id': 0}});
```

Produces the following error:

> [Error: Can't wait without a fiber]

*The error only occurs when I wrap the function in a Promise.*

For example, something like this will throw:

```
getRecordExample = function () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var record_name = Mongo_Collection_Name.findOne({_personId: userId}, {fields: {'_id': 0}});

  // do something

  // if no error
  deferred.resolve(record_name);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

If I use the Meteor Fibers library I don't get the error:

```
getRecordExample = function () {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
  var record_name

  Fiber(function () {
    record_name = Mongo_Collection_Name.findOne({_personId: userId});
  }).run()
  // do something

  // if no error
  deferred.resolve(record_name);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

but, the record_name variable is undefined outside the fiber, so I don't have a way to pass the variable outside of the Fiber scope as far as I can tell.

### A More Precise Example

This is a little long, so you have to scroll down to see it all.  I'm basically building a workflow here so there are processes and subprocesses.

```
// both/routes.js
Router.route('/get-route', function(req, res) {
  // get the userId then start the workflow below

  // using Promises here because these were firing concurrently
  Q(userId)
  .then(process_1)
  .then(process_2)
  .done();
}, { name: 'server-side-ir-route', where: 'server' }

// server.js
process_1 = function (userId) {
  sub_process_1(userId);

  sub_process_2(userId);

  return userId;
}

process_2 = function (userId) {
  sub_process_3(userId);

  sub_process_4(userId);

  return userId;
}

sub_process_1 = function (userId) {
  var result = get_record_1(userId);

  // do stuff with result

  // using Q library to call out to async fs.writeFile, return Promise
  fs_writeFile_promise(result)
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error in sub_process_1_write', error);
  })
  .done(function () {
    console.log('done with sub_process_1');
  }

  return userId;
}.future() // <-- if no future() here, the exception is thrown.

sub_process_2 = function (userId) {
  var result = get_record_2(userId);

  // do stuff with result

  // using Q library to call out to async fs.writeFile, return Promise
  fs_writeFile_promise(result)
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error in sub_process_1_write', error);
  })
  .done(function () {
    console.log('done with sub_process_1');
  }

  return userId;
}.future()

// async because of I/O operation (I think)
get_record_1 = function (userId) {
  var record_1 = Mongo_Collection_Name.findOne({'userId': userId});
  // do stuff
  return record_1;
}
get_record_2 = function (userId) {
  var record_2 = Mongo_Collection_Name.findOne({'userId': userId});
  // do stuff
  return record_2;
}

// async operation using Q library to return a Promise
fs_writeFile_promise = function (obj) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  fs.writeFile(obj.file, obj.datas, function (err, result) {
    if (err) deferred.reject(err);
    else deferred.resolve('write data completed');
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

For now, lets assume that the process_2 function is exactly like process_1

Also, we should assume I have console.log('step_start') and console.log('step_end') in each function.  This is what it would look like on the command line:

- start processes
- end processes
- start processes 1
- end processes 1
- start processes 2
- start sub processes 1
- getting record 1
- start sub processes 2
- getting record 2
- returning record 1
- end sub processes 1
- called writeData in sub process 1
- returning record 2
- called writeData in sub process 2
- end processes 2
- ending sub processes 1

The reason I had to place a Fiber (future) on the sub_process_1() function was because when I placed the function process_1() in the Q chain at the top I got the Error: Can't wait without a fiber].

If I remove the process_1() in the Q chain at the top and remove the .future() from sub_process_1() no exception is thrown.

### Questions

- Why does calling out to a Mongo collection within a Promise cause a
  fiber error within a Meteor application?
- Does calling a async function within a sync function in general cause the sync function to become a async function?
- How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you can do everything you want just by making sure to wrap all your async callbacks in Meteor.bindEnvironment(), so maybe show the route and file code.  You probably would not need to make separate use of fibers or promises unless you are trying to make some tasks in your callback chain concurrent.

Comment: I seemed to get it working by hooking a .future() on the end of the function above. I'm wrapping up for today, but I'll post more code tomorrow. I think the bindEnviornment (bE) is just a wrapper around a Fiber that contains some additional Meteor information -- so by using bE are we not using Fibers after all? Also, a Future is just sugar on a Fiber (which is what I'm using). I think the issue is, Mongo calls are considered I/O, which is handled by the OS and is async. So since I'm calling the DB outside of the Meteor environment & not wrapped in a Fiber behind the scenes, it's complaining.

Comment: What is the async call within `get_record_1_async()`?  I think you are mistakenly assuming that meteor mongo calls like `findOne()` are async and  adding a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: There's noting async about the get_record_1_async( ) function that's async besides it's name and the fact that I'm calling out to Mongo.  I can just remove the name and remove the .future() on the calling method sub_process_1( ) and I'll get the [Error: Can't wait without a fiber]... but this only occurs when I place process_1() in the Q chain at the top.

Comment: I'll edit my last example to change the name of the function and explain why I'm doing what I'm doing a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to solve this is wrap your asynchronous callbacks that use Meteor functions in [`Meteor.bindEnvironment()`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/556c0e28e94b9351cbf0b28e80a71a4e35f1362a/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js#L65).

If you are using the Meteor core [WebApp package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) to handle your server side route, the code would be like this (also in [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/yTDRGm4hSRBmEuo8N/rest)):

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(
  '/test',
  Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(req, res, next) {
    var someSyncData = Players.findOne();
    res.write(JSON.stringify(someSyncData));
    res.end();
  })
);
```

Working with fibers or promises yourself is unnecessary unless you are trying to get multiple async events to run concurrently.

To deal with file reading or other functions that are not already synchronous, Meteor also provides [`Meteor.wrapAsync()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) to make them synchronous.

There are also [packages and a help page](http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API) that give you other high level alternatives.